# Django - Existing DB Views and Foreign Keys

Tags: django, django-models

I have a simple view on the DB which selects from other DB's tables located on the same MSSQL Server to ultimately serve the collected info as a dropdown to the user.

So far I've added the Model with inspectdb:

```
class AutPricePlanView(models.Model):
      priceplan_name = models.CharField(db_column='PricePlan', max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True)

            class Meta:
                managed = False  # Created from a view. Don't remove.
                db_table = 'AUT_PricePlanView'
```

Also I have a second existing (Django Native) Model where I want to use the values from the view for a Dropdown Field (to keep everything in sync):

```
class PricePlanDownload(models.Model):
    requesting_user = models.CharField(blank=True, default=None, max_length=50, null=True)
    requested_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='documents/price_plan_uploads/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
    priceplan = models.ForeignKey(AutPricePlanView, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Makemigrations works fine but when I try to actually migrate I get the following issue: (shortened it a little bit)
*django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: ('42000', "[42000] [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Foreign key references object 'AUT_PricePlanView' which is not a user table. (1768) (SQLExecDirectW)")*

I would be really grateful if someone had an idea or a workaround since I can't figure out what the heck this has to do with a "user" table...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the view is not actually a table, you cannot set Foreign Key constraints. Since `ForeignKey`'s default `db_constraint` value is `True`, Django tries to set Foreign Key constraints when performing migrations. This is the reason the migration fails.

So, you can turn off the `db_constraint` option. And you can remove the existing migration file, and re-create the migration file. Then, the migration will success and you can keep everything in sync.

```
class PricePlanDownload(models.Model):
    ... other fields ...
    priceplan = models.ForeignKey(AutPricePlanView, null=True, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, db_constraint=False)
```

**Pro Tip:** You can review migration's SQL using `python manage.py sqlmigrate <appname> <migration number>`, like `python manage.py sqlmigrate yourapp 0002`.

---

Update: You can define `__str__` to display the correct value at the dropdown menu.

```
class AutPricePlanView(models.Model):
    priceplan_name = models.CharField(db_column='PricePlan', max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True, primary_key=True)  
    # null=False by default. See https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py#L132

    def __str__(self):
        return self.priceplan_name

    class Meta:
        managed = False  # Created from a view. Don't remove.
        db_table = 'AUT_PricePlanView'
```

Comment: Thanks! I needed to set " null=False, primary_key=True" also, otherwise the view would give an error on the non existing "id" column. Whats odd now is that the dropdown is not showing only the value (=***) but also a "AutPricePlan View object (***)"??

Comment: @zeitghaist I updated my answer. You can define `__str__` function at `AutPricePlanView`. Anyway, because of the `null` is `False` by default, you can remove `null=False` safely :)

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks so much!!! (Would like to upvote your answer, but I'm missing the reputation)